# how to modify a file in one commit , then pass the modification to following commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Let's say topic : A-B-C-D, there are 4 commits, echo commit to add one line to a.txt.

```
A => add "aaa " > a.txt  
B => add "bbb"  >>a.txt  
c => add "ccc"  >>a.txt  
D => add "ddd"  >>a.txt
```

what is my target is:
how to delete the whitespace at the end of first line of a.txt in each commit?

I don't want to manually modify it in each commit.  Are there good method like:
manually modified in A, then rebase to B,C,D ?

Comment: If you use the `rebase` command on commit `A`, all of the history from then on will have a version of a.txt without the white space.  Your test case is pretty simple so should be easy enough to try to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [`git filter-branch --tree-filter`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) with some script that filters out the white space.